# Incremental mode in Talend

Tags: java, sql-server, talend

I have 2 tables in my database-: Office  - 
[image]
 and office_import :
[image]

 The office table is fed by office_import table using incremental mode based on the office_name.
The field END_date of Office table is currently NULL, but I need to check in the office_name from office table does not exist in the office_import table, then the END_date needs to be updated with the current date, otherwise it shall remain NULL only.
I have created the job as below but the job keeps on executing for more than 3 hours and then I gets the I/O Timeout error. 
[image]
I have used the below script to feed the END_Date -
[image]
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tMap , you don't have any join key between tables row2 and row3 : you just have a cross join.
 Drag&drop "Office_name" from row2 onto row3.Import_office_name in order to get a proper left join. (you'll see the purple link between the two tables, indicating the join)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now although the query is taking only 3-5 min to execute, but the END date is not getting populated correctly. I want the ENd date of the Office_name  in oFFICE table to be set at system date only for the case when that Office_name does not exist itn office_import table. I have used the below but still getting NULL in the END_DATE -
row3.Import_office_name!=row1.Office_name?TalendDate.getCurrentDate():row3.END_DATE

Comment: There is no "row3.END_DATE" in your schema. Add it, or use row2.END_DATE instead.